# Understanding a case of Callback in C

Tags: c, callback

I want to understand what this code means actually, esp. the last part where the function is put into curly braces. Is the broadcast_open function somehow calling the function broadcast_recv? If yes, how?

```
static void broadcast_recv(struct broadcast_conn *c, const rimeaddr_t *from)
{
  printf("broadcast message received from %d.%d: '%s'\n",
         from->u8[0], from->u8[1], (char *)packetbuf_dataptr());
}

static const struct broadcast_callbacks broadcast_call = {broadcast_recv};
static struct broadcast_conn broadcast;

PROCESS_THREAD(example_broadcast_process, ev, data)
{

  broadcast_open(&broadcast, 129, &broadcast_call);

  ...

}

void broadcast_open(struct broadcast_conn *c, uint16_t channel, const struct broadcast_callbacks *u)   
{ 
      abc_open(&c->c, channel, &broadcast); 
      c->u = u; 
      channel_set_attributes(channel, attributes); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Here is the code for broadcast_open

Comment: void
broadcast_open(struct broadcast_conn *c, uint16_t channel,
   const struct broadcast_callbacks *u)
{
  abc_open(&c->c, channel, &broadcast);
  c->u = u;
  channel_set_attributes(channel, attributes);
}

Comment: What I want to know specifically is the syntax of those curly braces ... why and how have they been used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably seen simple variables initialized, e.g.:

```
int x = 4;
```

When it's an aggregate, such as a structure, braces are used around the initializer so the compiler knows where the initializer ends. In this case, it would appear that a function pointer is the first member of the struct.

```
int f(void) { return 1; }

struct t {
   int (*f)(void);
   int a, b, c;
   char *d, *e, *f;
} a_t_instance = {
    f
};
```

Someone can now call `f()` with `(*a_t_instance.f)()`, or even `a_t_instance.f()`

So yes, `broadcast_open` or something that it calls is probably calling `broadcast_receive,` using the pointer in the structure.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `broadcast_callbacks` is a struct defined something like this:

```
struct broadcast_callbacks
{
    void (*callback)(struct broadcast_conn *, const rimeaddr_t *from);
};
```

Then the line

```
static const struct broadcast_callbacks broadcast_call = {broadcast_recv};
```

creates a new struct object whose member points to the `broadcast_recv` function. This member can now be used to call the `broadcast_recv` (which is probably part of what `broadcast_open` does).